# Display hierarchy of entities

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008

I have the following simplified XML structure:

```
<Product>
  <Name>Product 1</Name>
  <Discount>
    <Name>Discount 1<Name>
    <Rate>10</Rate>
    <Amount>100</Amount>
  </Discount>
  <Discount>
    <Name>Discount 2<Name>
    <Rate>20</Rate>
    <Amount>200</Amount>
  </Discount>
</Product>
<Product>
  <Name>Product 2</Name>
  <Discount>
    <Name>Discount 1<Name>
    <Rate>30</Rate>
    <Amount>300</Amount>
  </Discount>
  <Discount>
    <Name>Discount 2<Name>
    <Rate>40</Rate>
    <Amount>400</Amount>
  </Discount>
</Product>
```

The structure is then processed by a report. What I would like to display is the following:

```
Product 1
  Discount 1 (10%) 100
  Discount 2 (20%) 200
Product 2
  Discount 1 (30%) 300
  Discount 2 (40%) 400
```

I have tried to structure a subreport as follows:

```
ReportHeader (contains a table header)
  Group 1 (grouped by Product.Internal_Id, with the product name)
  Group 2 (grouped by Discount.Internal_Id, with discount data)
  Details (suppressed)
  Footers (suppressed).
```

When I preview the result in my editor, it looks exactly as I want. However, when processed by the server, each product group lists all discounts for all products:

```
Product 1
  All discounts for all products
Product 2
  Same...
```

The version of my local report designer is 14.0.4.738. The version embedded in the server is 12.2.205.825.

How should I structure my report template in order to obtain the result I expect? Unfortunately, I have limited experience with Crystal Reports. I have tried many variations and many groupings, to no avail.

Comment: Are you sure you are viewing the same report in server that you have developed

Comment: Hello. Yes I am sure - I have downloaded the report from the server and tested it locally.

Comment: Grouping cant be changed what ever the version of report.....

Comment: What I have done is add a mark on the local report, then upload it to the server, then have it rendered - the final result is different from the preview (like I have described), and my mark is present, which is why I'm sure it's the same report. I'm truly perplexed.